# -fabi-version=6 (or =0) avoids this error with a change in mangling

Tags: c++, templates, name-mangling

I have code like so:

```
namespace MLX90393 {

struct status_t {
    // simplified for example, real implementation is more involved
    uint8_t data;
    explicit operator uint8_t const () { return 0; };
};
}

struct zyxt_t {
    uint16_t z;
    uint16_t y;
    uint16_t x;
    uint16_t t;
};
}

template <uint8_t A1, uint8_t A0, TwoWire &i2c, int8_t drdy_pin>
class MLX90393_raw {

public:
    MLX90393::status_t readMeasurement(uint8_t axis_mask, MLX90393::zyxt_t& result);

//
//  Implementation starts here
//
using namespace MLX90393;

template <uint8_t A1, uint8_t A0, TwoWire &i2c, int8_t drdy_pin>
status_t MLX90393_raw<A1, A0, i2c, drdy_pin>::
readMeasurement(uint8_t axis_mask, zyxt_t& result) {
// some implementation
}
```

The compliler complains like so:

```
MLX90393_raw.h:230: error: 'MLX90393::status_t MLX90393_raw<A1, A0, i2c, drdy_pin>::readMeasurement(uint8_t, MLX90393::zyxt_t&) [with unsigned char A1 = 0u; unsigned char A0 = 0u; TwoWire& i2c = (* & Wire); signed char drdy_pin = 10; uint8_t = unsigned char]' conflicts with a previous declaration
 status_t MLX90393_raw<A1, A0, i2c, drdy_pin>::
          ^
~/MLX90393_raw.h:230:10: note: previous declaration 'MLX90393::status_t MLX90393_raw<A1, A0, i2c, drdy_pin>::readMeasurement(uint8_t, MLX90393::zyxt_t&) [with unsigned char A1 = 0u; unsigned char A0 = 0u; TwoWire& i2c = (* & Wire); signed char drdy_pin = 10; uint8_t = unsigned char]'
~/MLX90393_raw.h:230:10: note: -fabi-version=6 (or =0) avoids this error with a change in mangling

'MLX90393::status_t MLX90393_raw<A1, A0, i2c, drdy_pin>::readMeasurement(uint8_t, MLX90393::zyxt_t&) [with unsigned char A1 = 0u; unsigned char A0 = 0u; TwoWire& i2c = (* & Wire); signed char drdy_pin = 10; uint8_t = unsigned char]' conflicts with a previous declaration
```

I have other similar members in my class and they compile fine.
If I add the -fabi-version=6 (or 0) then it compiles fine. However my library is aiming at Arduino users and this would require them to patch the platform.txt file. This in turn will probably discourage most users of the library.

The issue is that  [according to the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html) gcc 4.* defaults to version 2. So this should be fixable by defaulting to 0.

What is wrong with readMeasurement? Or how can I convince the compiler to mangle it without setting the compiler option from outside?

Comment: You lack guards against multiple inclusion ... (like #pragma once)?

Comment: The file is definitely included only once. At this time the project consists of only two files. Anyway I have include guards in place. I replaced them by #pragma once --> did not change anything at all.

Comment: Perhaps try to find what is up by erasing code and compiling until the error stops. Posted code does not compile because of misplaced }.

Comment: Here is the full file: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ea3e450ec3562b99b65e94fce50941e9

Comment: May be it does not like anonymous struct in union there or apparent usage of designated initializers data_t data = {.buffer = {}}; that is not C++.

Comment: Other issue may be that since only return value of different instantiations of that template differs it may be that it causes issue with particular name mangling scheme when there are multiple different instantiations.

Comment: It compiles with all fabi-versions but 1 and 2. However I would have expected that the Arduino IDE does not explicitly set it and thus the default version (which is 0) should be applied. If I set it explicitly this works perfectly well. Seems the Arduino IDE does something behind my back. How would I find out which ABI version it actually uses?

Comment: There is only one instantiation of the this specific template.

Comment: I have noticed that for Arduino it is odd C++ compiler. Sometimes we need to move enum into separate header just to get some such strange error to be fixed. It is because it does generate some code on its own behind scenes.

Comment: I am aware of this behind my back mechanism. However this is a separate h file and it did not touch it. My impression is that it sets an abi version != 0 behind my back. However I could not find any place (incl. platform.txt) where this would be configured. If I configure fabi-version = 0 in platform.txt then the issue is fixed.

Comment: By now I found that gcc 4.* defaults to abi version 2: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html